# Springboot with JPA: inner join with same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have an entity as below:

```sql
    @Entity(name = "TEMP_TABLE")
    public class TempEntity {
        @Id
        private UUID id;
        private String name;
        private String addressLine;
        @Convert(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
        private ZonedDateTime createdDateTime;    
    }
```

I want to perform the below query using `JPA` with `criteria builder`:

```sql
    SELECT
        T1.* 
    FROM
        TEMP_TABLE T1 
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                name,
                MAX(created_date_time) AS MaxDateTime        
            FROM
                TEMP_TABLE 
            GROUP BY
                name
        ) T2             
            ON T1.name = T2.name                 
            AND T1.created_date_time = T2.MaxDateTime;
```

The purpose is to get the latest record (with all columns) for each name from `TEMP_TABLE`.

Can you help me here.

Comment: It looks like this `TEMP_TABLE.*` should be `T1.*` or `T2.*`?

Comment: My apologies, I have corrected it now

Answer (score 0):

Change the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE T1 WHERE T1.created_date_time = 
(SELECT MAX(T2.created_date_time) FROM TEMP_TABLE T2 WHERE T2.name = T1.name GROUP BY T2.name);
```

Can implemented like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TempTable> cq = cb.createQuery(TempTable.class);

Root<TempTable> rootT1 = cq.from(TempTable.class);

//Create Subquery
Subquery<Date> sq = cq.subquery(Date.class);
Root<TempTable> rootT2sq = sq.from(TempTable.class);
//Set Condition between T1 y T2
sq.where(cb.equal(rootT1.get(TempTable_.name),rootT2sq.get(TempTable_.name)));
sq.select(cb.greatest(rootT2sq.get(TempTable_.createdDateTime)));
sq.groupBy(rootT2sq.get(TempTable_.name));

//Set condition equal max
cq.where(cb.equal(rootT1.get(TempTable_.createdDateTime),sq.getSelection()));
cq.select(rootT1);

entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```